# SQL Server - Top Saleperson Per Region

Tags: sql-server, grouping, having

```
    SELECT region, person, sum(dollars) as thousands
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY region, person
    ORDER BY region, sum(dollars) desc
```

The SQL above produces a complete list of sales people per region like this

```
    region person      thousands

    canada mike smith  $114
    canada joe blog    $76
    canada pete dodd   $45
    usa    john doe    $253
    usa    jane smyth  $120
    europe pieter tsu  $546
    europ  mike lee    $520
```

If I'm only interested in showing the top salesperson per region (as below), how can I best do that?

```
    region person      thousands

    canada mike smith  $114
    usa    john doe    $253
    europe pieter tsu  $546
```

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: border case: what would you like to show in case there are 2 great sales guys that are equal top performers in the same region? just any? both? or?

Comment: Why are you using count?  Count would just give the number of records that match, not the sum of sales.  Unless every sale is exactly $1000...
You should use Sum if you want the sum...

Comment: doh! i had a brain-fart with count. (i'm not actually using this query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like burnall suggested. I wasn't getting much love with the "top 1 with ties" part, so I made the whole thing a subquery and chose rows where ranking = 1.

```
select *
from
(
     select region, 
            person, 
            rank() over(partition by region order by sum(dollars) desc) as ranking
     from sales 
     group by region, 
              person 

) temp
where ranking = 1
```

Note that this also works for ties since rank() seems to place the same ranking on sums that are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the max() aggregate. It's probably less efficient than the other alternatives because you'll be doing group by twice

```
SELECT region,person,max(thousands) FROM
(SELECT region, person, count(*) as thousands
FROM sales
GROUP BY region, person) tmp
GROUP BY region, person
ORDER BY region, max(thousands) desc
```

Comment: Did you try this ? **Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.**

Comment: No I didn't. The alternative I wrote now I didn't try also, just going by memory. Which usually fails me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server 2005+ you could do this using a [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Have a look at this full example.

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE(
        region VARCHAR(50), 
        person VARCHAR(50),
        Sales FLOAT
)



INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','mike smith',1 
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','mike smith',1
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','mike smith',1
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','mike smith',1

INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','joe blog',1
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','joe blog',1 

INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'canada','pete dodd',1 


INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'usa','john doe',1
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'usa','john doe',1

INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'usa','jane smyth',1

INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'europe','pieter tsu',1
INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'europe','pieter tsu',1 

INSERT INTO @sales SELECT 'europe','mike lee',1

;WITH Counts AS(
        SELECT  region, 
                person, 
                count(*) as thousands 
        FROM    @sales 
        GROUP BY    region, 
                    person
), CountVals AS(
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY region ORDER BY thousands DESC) ROWID
        FROM     Counts
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CountVals
WHERE   ROWID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 and above use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY`. Following should work (not tested, and probably can be shortened):

```
WITH total_sales
AS (SELECT      region, person, count(*) as thousands
    FROM        sales
    GROUP BY    region, person
    ORDER BY    region, count(*) desc
)
, ranked_sales
AS (SELECT      region, person, thousands,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY thousands DESC, person) AS region_rank
    FROM        total_sales
)
SELECT  region, person, thousands
FROM    ranked_sales
WHERE   region_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I do not understand why count(*) is in $.
My solution is similar to existing, but shorter and I believe faster

```
select top 1 with ties region, person, rank() over(partition by region order by count(*) desc)
from sales
group by region, person
order by 3
```

Comment: I wasn't having much luck with the "top 1 with ties" part, so I got rid of it and ran it as a subquery selecting only rankings of 1. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What is a problem with a top 1 with ties? I have checked it on a simple test. Show your query and maybe we can improve it even more)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too difficult.  This query will do exactly what you want.

```
 select distinct region,
        (select top 1 person
        from Sales s2 where s2.region = s1.region
        group by person
        order by SUM(dollars) desc) as person,
            (select top 1 SUM(dollars) 
        from Sales s2 where s2.region = s1.region
        group by person
        order by SUM(dollars) desc) as thousands
        from sales s1
```

Answer (score 0):

to find top 5 salesperson by sales for each region

```
select *
from
(
     select region, 
            [Customer Name],
            rank() over(partition by region order by sum(sales) desc) as ranking
     from Orders 
     group by region, [Customer Name] 
) temp
where ranking between 1 and 5
```